# How to pass options value to a function in react?

Tags: reactjs

How to pass option's value to a function on select ?

```
submit = (selectedOption) => {
  console.log('Selected value:',selectedOption);
}

render(){
    return
       <select onChange={this.submit}>
          <option value="Bangalore">Bangalore</option>
          <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
          <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
       </select>
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to pass the value manually, you can access the selected value by `event object`: `event.target.value`

Write it like this:

```
submit = (event) => {
  console.log('Selected value:', event.target.value);
}

render(){
   return(
      <select onChange={this.submit}>
         <option value="Bangalore">Bangalore</option>
         <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
         <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
     </select>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The callback for `onChange` receives an event object as parameter. To access the selected value, use `event.target.value`. E.g.

```
<select onChange={(event) => this.submit(event.target.value)}>
```